# Using Numerical and Complex Categorical data with a Random Forest Prediction Model

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, categorical-data

I'm attempting to create a Random Forest Prediction Model using both Numerical and Categorical Data. I know that using encoding, Categorical data can be converted to Numerical data, but what do you do if you have complex Categorical data?

For example, I have categorical data which are paragraphs written by humans, this would be very difficult and expensive to encode into numerical data. However, it's very important that this data is classified and considered for my model to work properly. I also have numerical data that can be easily understood by my model, however, I want to be able to use both my complex categorical data and my numerical data to train the prediction model.

I have tried using One-Hot-Encoding and other forms of preprocessing to convert my Categorical data into usable numerical data. However, it is very inefficient to convert this data, and my model has a hard time understanding what exactly the converted data means. I'm looking for a way to train my model on both Categorical data and Numerical data at the same time.

Is there a form of encoding that can work with large amounts of text? Or am I going down the wrong track? For reference, I have been using sklearn to implement my Random Forst model.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing some vocabulary in the area. Once you get the keywords, you should be able to help yourself.

> I have categorical data which are paragraphs written by humans.

This is free-form text data, not categorical data. Therefore, you need to apply proper text pre-processing methods, not categorical encoders.

The keyword is "bag of words". You must transform text paragraphs to bags-of-words.

In the Scikit-Learn context, take a look at the [feature extraction](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html) tutorial. After that, have fun with `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer` or `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer` transformers.